# Socket.emit brings multiple values

Tags: node.js, angular, express, socket.io

socket.emit inside socket.on concatenating the same value after every emitting.
Here is my code on server-side

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
let balance = 6000;


console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('giveValue',function(data){
        if(data.msg==="New Value"){
          let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 - 50);
          balance += x;
          socket.emit('takeValue',{balance:balance,value:x});
        }
  });

  socket.on('disconnect',function(){
      console.log('User disconnected');
  });
  socket.on('getBalance',(data)=>{
    if(data.msg==='bringBalance'){
      socket.emit('ubalance',{data:balance});
    }
  })

});
```

And this one is on client side, for client side I'm using Angular 6

```
constructor() {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:4000');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.socket.emit('getBalance',{msg:"bringBalance"});
    this.socket.on('ubalance',(data)=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.balance=data.data;
    });
  }

  getSum(event) {
    this.socket.open();
    this.socket.emit('giveValue',{msg:"New Value"});
    this.socket.on('takeValue', (data) => {
       this.balance=data.balance;
       console.log("Value====="+data.value) + "\n";
       console.log("Balance======"+data.balance);

    });
  }
```

After every click runs getSum() function and its generating random values in back-end add that values to balance.All this doing my back-end side. 
So the issue is that socket.on("takeValue") after every click brings one more 
same value.How can I fix this part.Sorry for my language mistakes, I hope you understood me.Thanks for attention and for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you declare `.on` events inside the functions and each time you run the function, you set new listener to `takeValue` event. Try below snippet or somthing like this

```
constructor() {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:4000');
}

this.socket.on('ubalance',(data)=>{
    console.log(data);
    this.balance=data.data;
    });

this.socket.on('takeValue', (data) => {
    this.balance=data.balance;
    console.log("Value====="+data.value) + "\n";
    console.log("Balance======"+data.balance);

    });

ngOnInit() {
    this.socket.emit('getBalance',{msg:"bringBalance"});

}

getSum(event) {
    this.socket.open();
    this.socket.emit('giveValue',{msg:"New Value"});

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I found how to solve this problem, I just declared those functions in ngOnInit .And it works fine. Thank you one more time Milad Aghamohammadi.